# Is android asynctask always so slow

Tags: android, performance, android-asynctask

I'm using an asynctask to run a client protocol. The asynctask works fine, however it takes a (very noticable) few seconds to start running.

I've done some debugging and the button that calls the execute remains highlighted for several seconds, then onPreExecute() fires, and the process bar that I have running starts.

So my question is simply: is Asynctask always this slow to start or is there a chance of some sort of problem here?

Here's the button (and the onClickListener) in question. This code is found in onCreate(Bundle SavedInstanceState):

```
mSave = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
mSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
        "marker", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    if (portrait != null && !mComments.getText().toString().equals("")) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            checked[i] = checkBoxes[i].isChecked();
            checkBoxFields[i] = checkBoxes[i].getText().toString();
        }
        new ClientProtocol().execute();
     }
    }
});
```

Here's onPreExecute(), although I'm pretty sure the pause is somewhere before this:

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    mProgress = 0;
    mLoad.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mSave.setClickable(false);

    mFinal = "";

    mClientThoughts = mComments.getText().toString();
    mCheckBoxes = checkBoxFields;
    mChecked = checked;

    mBaos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    portrait.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, mBaos);
    mClientImage = mBaos.toByteArray();
}
```

Comment: I have had some issue with AsynTask in the past.  Usually they were down to how much other stuff was running in the phone at the same time.  In general, I've noticed that in emulator it would take longer to start than in an actual phone.  Yet, in a physical phone, I had seen a 2-3 seconds delay if I had angry birds and an ebook reader with a large book open both loaded.  This was due to the OS having to unload some tasks before it had resources available to create/start your AsyncTask thread.

Comment: There must be another problem here. `AsyncTask` works fine for me.

Comment: Cheers for letting me know. I'm running on a Motorola Xoom and it's the first and only app (other than the few that start automatically) that's running.

Comment: Could you paste some code? Asynctasks will be as slow as the task they are coded to run :-)

Comment: I've added the code that calls the asynctask. I can add the ClientProtocol class if you would like.

Comment: More interested in the onPreExecute() code of the ClientProtocol task. Your UI thread is working too hard on something.

Comment: I've added that code for you aswell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description seems like the delay is even before your onPreExecute() fires? Is there perhaps something delaying your button processing (maybe handler?) causing this?

Comment: Yes, the delay is before onPreExecute() fires. Within the onClickListener that calls the execute there's an if statement and a very short loop beforehand. Although I took them out briefly and problem persisted.

Comment: It seems you are doing quite a lot of stuff in your onPreExecute(), you may need to rethink your design and see if there is some way you can do this elsewhere prior to this (or maybe in the doInBackground()) as this will be done on every call to onPreExecute()?